# lead conversion using apex class....but when clicking on save button lead,account,contact and opportunity are not getting saved...pls help me out

Tags: apex-email-service

```
public without sharing class LeadClass{

public Lead__c myLead{get;set;}
    public LeadClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    mylead= new Lead__c();
     this.mylead= (Lead__c )Controller.getRecord();

    }



 public pageReference save(){
         myLead = new Lead__c();
         Database.Insert(myLead, FALSE); 
          system.debug('lllllllllllll'+myLead.id);

        Account a = new Account();
         a.Name =myLead.Company__c;
        //a.Company__c = l.Company__c;
         //a.AccountId = lid;
         a.Address1__c =myLead.Address1__c;
         a.Address2__c =myLead.Address2__c;
         a.Id = myLead.Id;

         a.Industry = myLead.Industry__c;
         a.Phone = myLead.Phone__c;
        a.Fax = myLead.FAX__c;
        a.PAN_Card_No__c =myLead.PAN_Card_No__c;
        a.CST_No__c = myLead.CST_No__c;
        a.Parent_Company__c = myLead.Parent_Company__c;
        a.Description = myLead.Description__c;
        a.Segment__c = myLead.Segment__c;
        a.TIN_No__c = myLead.TIN_No__c;
        a.Verticals__c =myLead.Verticals__c;
        a.Website = myLead.Website__c;
        a.Zip_Postal_Code__c = myLead.Zip_Postal_Code__c;
        a.State__c =myLead.State__c;
        a.City__c = myLead.City__c;

         Database.Insert(a, FALSE);   
        system.debug('aaaaaaaaaaaaa'+a.id);

        contact c = new contact();
         c.Id = myLead.Id;
     c.Alternate_Email__c =myLead.Alternate_Email__c;
     c.Description = myLead.Description__c;
     c.Email =myLead.Email__c;
     c.FirstName = myLead.Name;
     c.Fax =myLead.FAX__c;
     c.LastName = myLead.Last_Name__c;
     c.Salutation = myLead.Salutation__c;
     c.Phone = myLead.Phone__c;
         c.FirstName =myLead.Name;
        c.AccountID = a.id; 

           Database.Insert(c, FALSE);  
           system.debug('cccccccccccccccc'+c.id);
           /* Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
         o.Id = myLead.Id;
        // o.Name = myLead.Name;
        o.Name = myLead.Company__c;
        o.CurrencyIsoCode = myLead.CurrencyIsoCode;
        Database.Insert(o, FALSE);  
         system.debug(o);*/

    return null;





            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see in your code:

First, I think you want to implement the [Lead conversion Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_dml_convertLead). Until you do that, you can't do anything similar to the following:

```
a.Id = myLead.Id; // You can't specify the Id when inserting a new account

c.Id = myLead.Id; // You can't specify the Id when inserting a new contact
```

Instead, you need to be doing something similar to the following first:

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

Once you've applied the lead conversion class, then you can use some of it's other methods like the following:

```
getLeadID() 

getAccountId();

getContactId();

setOpportunityName(String) ;

setDoNotCreateOpportunity(Boolean);
```

It appears to me, that using the conversion class was the step that was missing in your class. Once you do the conversion, you'll be able to specify the Ids and other values you were attempting to assign and then update or upsert them.